# Using vue-cli-service in command line

Tags: npm, vue-cli

I am a newbie to npm and vue cli so my apologies beforehand. I created a vue package using npm and under scripts inside the package.json I see:
"scripts": {
  "serve": "vue-cli-service serve"
}

When I try entering vue-cli-service serve in the command line I get:

'vue-cli-service' is not recognized as an internal or external command

but when i enter npm run serve, the command works fine. Why can't I get vue-cli-service to work directly from the command line?

Comment: most likely it is not on the path. Does './node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service' work?